# Secondary repeater w/ ObjectDataSource databind event fired from another repeater's click event?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, repeater

I'm having trouble managing how to call upon databind from clicking on a row over an already populated repeater that will populate data regarding the row clicked TO another repeater on the same page.

I've succeeded doing that with postback, calling a jquery click event of that row, taking the data of the specific row and passing it onto a "Querystring" and after postpack, it will be pushed into a Session which the ObjectDataSource of the secondary repeater will recognize and populate the data tables accordingly.

The problem is, I must do it without a postback or in other words purely on client side.

What's the best method to do so? I'm really confused, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't exactly any built-in way to do databinding with repeater on client-side. So the simplest way will be either use PageMethods or webservice that takes your parameter and returns data. Then you will have to create your repeater markup on client-side and populate it with the data received.

[Sample 1](http://encosia.com/2008/06/26/use-jquery-and-aspnet-ajax-to-build-a-client-side-repeater/) 
[Sample 2](http://www.musahafalir.com/2011/01/12/asynchronously-binding-repeater-with-jquery-ajax/)

Comment: Many thanks for the comment, I've already saw the first  sample and tried to mess with it a bit, However it seems a bit difficult for my current level, What about Master-Details method with "SelectedIndexChanged Event" to activate the Details control?, I'm open for other controls but Repeaters.. But still I want to save out the postback to not to be called upon selecting an event.